# Creating many similar newtypes/typeclass instances in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, newtype

I am a beginner in Haskell and trying to learn about typeclasses and types. I have the following example (which represents a real problem in algebra that I am working on), in which I define a type which just wraps Num instances, and a typeclass which defines a binary operation `baz`.

```
newtype Foo i = B i deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

class Bar k where
    baz :: k -> k -> k

instance Num k => Bar (Foo k) where
    baz (B a) (B b) = B (f a b)

f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
f a b = a + b
```

When defining `Bar` to be an instance of this, I realize that I want to be able to "vary" the function `f` with the type. To be clear: I want to supply a function `f :: Num a => a -> a -> a` and get back a new type `Foo` which is an instance of `Bar`. Say that I want to do this 5, 10 times with the only difference being different functions `f`. I can of course copy and paste the code above, but I wonder if there is another way?

It seems to me that I'm confusing things. What is the best way of doing something like this in Haskell? Is this a good choice of design, what am I thinking right/wrong and why?

EDIT: I realize that a concrete example might help to make the question clearer (beware that it may seem complicated, I was not able to simplify the code more than this. The question above contains the same information I think): the typeclass I am interested in is `Algebra k v` from the library [HaskellForMaths](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellForMaths):

```
class Algebra k b where
    unit :: k -> Vect k b
    mult :: Vect k (Tensor b b) -> Vect k b
```

Here `k` is a field (a mathematical structure such as the real or complex numbers), while `v` is a choice of basis in a vector space. I would want to use it something like this

```
newtype Basis i = T i deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

type Expression k = Vect k (Basis Int)

instance Algebra k Basis where
    unit x = x *> return I
    mult = linear mult'
           where mult' (T x ,T y) = comm x y
           where comm a b = sum $ map (\c -> structure a b c *> t c) [0..n]

t :: Int -> Expression k
t a = return (T a)
```

and then vary the map `structure` as I please. Here the type `T` is just a convenient way of writing abstract basis elements `T 1, T 2, ...`. The reason I want to do it is the standard mathematical definition of an algebra in terms of its *structure constants* (here: `structure`). To summarize: I want to be able to vary the function `f` (preferably not at compile time?) and get back an algebra. This may be a bad design decision: if so, why?

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you intend to use this? And/or maybe provide a second instance to make the redundancy clear? More descriptive names could be helpful as well. Could `Foo` be a `Functor`/`Applicative` to use something like `f <$> B a <*> B b`

Comment: That `Bar` typeclass looks like a `Semigroup`. If the binary operation also has identity, it could be a `Monoid`.

Comment: Can you skip the newtype and typeclass entirely and just pass around `(+)` (or whatever other functions you want)?

Comment: I provided an example of how I intend to use it! I am short of time at the moment and will try to clarify more later, in the meantime thanks for all the replies! I will need some time to answer in a meaningful way if I could skip the typeclass, monoid properties etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reflection](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-2.1.2/docs/Data-Reflection.html).  This is a fairly advanced technique, and there may be better ways to solve your problem, but the way you have stated it it seems like this is what you're looking for.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Reflection
import Data.Proxy

class Bar k where
    baz :: k -> k -> k

newtype Foo f i = B i       -- f is a type level representation of your function
   deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance (Num k, Reifies f (k -> k -> k)) => Bar (Foo f k) where
    baz (B a) (B b) = B (reflect (Proxy :: Proxy f) a b)

mkFoo :: forall i r. (i -> i -> i) -> i
      -> (forall f. Reifies f (i -> i -> i) => Foo f i -> r) -> r
mkFoo f x c = reify f (\(p :: Proxy f) -> c (B x :: Foo f i))

main = do
    mkFoo (+) 5 $ \foo1 -> do
    print $ foo1 `baz` B 5  -- 10

    mkFoo (*) 5 $ \foo2 -> do
    print $ foo2 `baz` B 5  -- 25

    print $ foo1 `baz` foo2 -- type error
```

There is a lot going on here, so a few notes.

```
Reifies f (k -> k -> k)
```

is a constraint that means that `f` is a type-level representation of a function of type `k -> k -> k`.  When we `reflect (Proxy :: Proxy f)` (a fancy way of passing the type `f` to `reflect` since explicit type application was not until recently allowed), we get the function itself back out.

Now to the nasty signature of `mkFoo`

```
mkFoo :: forall i r. (i -> i -> i) -> i
      -> (forall f. Reifies f (i -> i -> i) => Foo f i -> r) -> r
```

The first `forall` is there for [`ScopedTypeVariables`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables), so we can refer to the type variables within the body of the function.  The second one is a genuine [rank-2 type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Rank-N_types),

```
(forall f. Reifies f (i -> i -> i) => Foo f i -> r) -> r
```

and it is a common encoding of an existential type, since Haskell doesn't have first class existentials.  You can read this type as

```
exists f. ( Reifies f (i -> i -> i) , Foo f i )
```

or some such—it *returns a type* `f` together with evidence that `f` is a type-level representation of a function `i -> i -> i`, and a `Foo f i`.  Observe in `main` that to use this "existential", we call the function with continuation passing style, that is

```
mkFoo (+) 5 $ \foo -> -- what to do with foo
```

Within the function, `foo` behaves like it has type `Foo f0 Integer` where `f0` is a brand new type made just for this function.

It's quite nice that it won't let us `baz` together `Foo`s from different `f`s, but unfortunately it's not smart enough to allow us to `baz` together `Foo`s made with the same function using different calls to `mkFoo`, so:

```
mkFoo (+) 5 $ \foo1 -> mkFoo (+) 5 $ \foo2 -> foo1 `baz` foo2  -- type error
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not that different to the answer by luqui, but instead of defining the mapping from an phantom type `f` to a concrete function at runtime using `reify` we do this at compile time. This makes the code a bit simpler and easier to use.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Bar k where
  baz :: k -> k -> k

-- Foo has now another phantom type variable, that we use to pick the 
-- desired f.
newtype Foo f k = B k

-- | GetF is used to retrieve a function for a given type label.
class GetF f k where
  appF :: Foo f k -> Foo f k -> Foo f k

-- Now we can make an instance for Bar if we have an instance for GetF
instance GetF f k => Bar (Foo f k) where
  baz x y = appF x y


-- = Usage example

-- | Add is just a label. We never use it at value level.
data Add

instance Num k => GetF Add k where
  appF (B x) (B y) = B (x + y)

example :: Foo Add Int
example = B 1 `baz` B 2 -- = B 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a supplement to my other answer, the solution I would actually suggest if your intention is to solve the practical problem rather than explore what is possible. It just converts the typeclass to "dictionary passing style", and doesn't use any fancy extensions or anything.

```
data Bar k = Bar { baz :: k -> k -> k }

newtype Foo i = B i

fooBar :: (i -> i -> i) -> Bar (Foo i)
fooBar f = Bar { baz = \(B x) (B y) -> B (f x y) }
```

Then when you have a function that uses this, pass it a `Bar` dictionary:

```
doThingsWithFoos :: Bar (Foo Int) -> Foo Int -> Foo Int -> Foo Int
doThingsWithFoos bar a b = baz bar a (baz bar a b)
```

It's a bit more verbose to use, but this kind of solution is remarkably flexible.  Dictionaries are completely first-class, so, for example, you can start doing higher level manipulations on the dictionaries themselves:

```
transportBar :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> Bar a -> Bar b
transportBar f finv bar = Bar { baz = \x y -> f (baz bar (finv x) (finv y)) }

sumBar :: (Num a) => Bar a -> Bar a -> Bar a
sumBar bar1 bar2 = Bar { baz = \x y -> baz bar1 x y + baz bar2 x y }
```

Both of these transformations would be a major pain using typeclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `f` only depends on `k`, you could define another class which would pack such a function like so:

```
newtype Foo i = B i deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

class PreBar k where
  preBar :: k -> k -> k

class Bar k where
  baz :: k -> k -> k

instance (Num k, PreBar k) => Bar (Foo k) where
    baz (B a) (B b) = B (preBar a b)
```